# Xamarin Forms Flyout menu at bottom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Is there anyway to set one menu item at the bottom of shell like the image?

so you will have all normal menus:

and then at the bottom of it a:

```
<MenuItem Text="Logout" IconImageSource="logout"
              Command="{Binding SignOutCommand}">
    </MenuItem>
```

[image]

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to define the `MenuItemTemplate` as a workaround to achieve this:

```
<MenuItem Text="Logout" IconImageSource="logout"
          Command="{Binding SignOutCommand}">
    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                   Margin="0,300,0,0"             //You need to adjust the margin value yourself 
                   HeightRequest="30" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="0,300,0,0"           //You need to adjust the margin value yourself 
                   Text="{Binding Text}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Will this be valid whatever is the screen size?

Comment: You need adjust the Margin value according to your screen size.